# how to use django_select2 in form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i have a ModelChoiceField and it's realy big so i want to use ModelSelect2Widget to filter the choices in my ModelChoiceField . i used this code but he didnt work
i want like this 
https://www.drupal.org/files/project-images/select2.png
this is my code

```
class Ajout4 (forms.Form):

client=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Suivre.objects.all(),widget=ModelSelect2Widget(model=Suivre,search_fields=['numcniF'],dependent_fields={'numcniF': 'numcniF'},max_results=500,))
montant=forms.FloatField(required=True,widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Paye MTN '}))
```

myhtml

```
<form method="post">
<div class="container">
<div>{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

 {% csrf_token %}
 {{con|crispy}}

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" > SAVE</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">RESET</button>
```